# Sidebar hidden by default instead of showing

Tags: javascript, python, flask, bootstrap-4

I have built the sidebar with Flask/Bootstrap, all is good, except when the page loads, the navbar is hidden instead of showing.

This is the HTML code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<!-- Sidebar section -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand d-flex flex-column align-item-start" id="sidebar">
  <div class="p-4 pt-5">

<!-- User image -->
  <div class="text-center">
    <img src="{{url_for('static',filename='profile_pics/two.jpg')}}" class="rounded" alt="Profile">
  </div>

 <!-- Navbar menus -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex flex-column mt-5 w-100">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown w-100">
          <a href="#equitiesSubmenu" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-light pl-4" id="equitiesSubmenu" role="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">Equities</a>
          <ul class="collapse lisst-unstyled" id="equitiesSubmenu">
              <li><a href="{{url_for('core.simulator')}}" class="dropdown-item text-light pl-4 p-2">Simulator</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{url_for('core.portfolio')}}" class="dropdown-item active text-light pl-4 p-2">Portfolio</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>       
  </ul>

  <br>
  <div class="footer">
      <p>
          Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> All rights reserved | <i class="icon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href="#" target="_blank">#</a>
      </p>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- JS To Activate Sidebar -->
    <!-- bootstrap js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- custom js -->
    <script>
        var menu_btn = document.querySelector("#menu-btn")
        var sidebar = document.querySelector("#sidebar")
        var container = document.querySelector(".my-container")
        menu_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            sidebar.classList.toggle("active-nav")
            container.classList.toggle("active-cont")
        })

    </script>
```

and this is the css file:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: -300px;
    background-color: #212529;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.nav-link {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

.nav-link:active,
.nav-link:focus,
.nav-link:hover {
    background-color: #c0c2c5;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #be1ca9;
}

.dropdown-item:active,
.dropdown-item:focus,
.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: #a81219;
}

.my-container {
    transition: 0.4s;
}


/* for navbar */

.active-nav {
    margin-left: 0;
}


/* for main section */

.active-cont {
    margin-left: 250px;
}

.footer p {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
```

I edited the css and HTML files many times to ensure I haven't set a value to hide it, but I still don't see where I made set to not show by default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can make out by reading your provided code, the `nav` is only visible when it has the class `active-nav` on it.

You add this class to the `nav` when `menu_btn` is clicked.
Since this class isn't present on the `nav` element in the HTML code by default, it stays hidden when you load the page.

To make it visible by default, your `nav` should have the `active-nav` class on it in your HTML code